# Please Help Explain This Code That Removes Leading Zeros (EPI-Python)

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting

```py
res = [0,0,1,2,3]
res = res[next((i for i, x in enumerate(res) if x != 0), len(res)):] or [0]
# res => [1,2,3]
```

Can someone please explain what the `res[next((i for i, x in enumerate(res) if x != 0), len(res)):] or [0]` is doing? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The expanded version of the one-line code is

```
index = len(res) # initialize the index
for i, r in enumerate(res): # find index to the first non-zero element
    if r != 0:
        index = i
        break
# if there is no non-zero element, index will be pointed to len(res)
res = res[index:] # remove all non-zero leading element
if len(res) == 0:
    res = [0] # if there is no non-zero element
```

The idea is to remove all leading non-zero elements from the array, if all elements are zero, keep one only.

i.e.

[0,0,1] => [1]

[1,2,0] => [1,2,0]

[0,0,0] => [0]

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Burning Alcohol 's answer,

1. `(i for i, x in enumerate(res) if x != 0)` creates an iterator, equivalent to `iter([2,3,4])`
2. `next((i for i, x in enumerate(res) if x != 0)` will show the first element of the iterator, since the iterator is [2,3,4], the first element is 2
3. `res[next((i for i, x in enumerate(res) if x != 0), len(res)):]` is same as `res[2:]`, which is equivalent to "2 to end", and this gives us [1,2,3]

I just started learning Python, and this is really cool, thanks yall!

Comment: glad you find that helpful, happy coding!